# I am getting an error " The object invoked has disconnected from its clients" when automating my website

Tags: vba, excel

Below is the code i am using

```
Sub IE_try()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

IE.Navigate "my site"

Application.StatusBar = "Submitting"

While IE.Busy
DoEvents
Wend

delay 5
IE.Document.getElementByClass("ms-textSmall ms-srch-sb-prompt ms-helperText").Value = "abc"

IE.Documnet.getElementByName("ms-srch-sb-searchImg").Click

End Sub
```

Error message:

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a strange error. In general your code is a bit wrong - you should use `getElementsByClassname` and not `getElementsByClass`. Here is something to start with, working for the StackOverflow site, writing `abv` in the search engine.

```
Option Explicit

Sub IE_try()

    Dim Element     As Object
    Dim IE          As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True

    IE.Navigate "http://stackoverflow.com"

    While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    Set Element = IE.Document.getElementsByClassname("f-input js-search-field")
    Element.Item.Value = "abv"

End Sub
```